# Batch file not executing from PHP code while running from Command Prompt

Tags: php

I tried to execute a batch file from the command prompt (even not running it as  Administrator) and it works fine as expected. But I tried the same file through PHP code and find its not working.

Below is the code I am trying to achieve

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");               
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c " . __DIR__ . "\\execute_qrys.bat", 0, false);
```

Also I tried exec command to execute the file. But nothing is working.
Can anyone please help me to get this done.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `2>errors.log` to end of file to get errors from file execution.

Comment: Not throwing any error. However the same code works now. I think its permission issue with the .bat file.